# Allow access to only non-logged in user in django

Tags: python, django

In django how can I prevent certain pages to be displayed to the logged in user. For example login page, signup page. That is I would like to prevent logged in user to reach login and signup pages.

One way of doing it would be to write my own view for login and in that view check if user has already logged in, and if he is, redirect to some other page.

Is there a better way to achieve this? Like some decorator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look at the user_passes_test decorator.

You would do something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
@user_passes_test(lambda u: not u.is_authenticated())
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

user_passes_test receives a function. Where that function receives the User object. That function must return a bool to determine whether or not the view should be executed.

If you're not using the User object to authenticate users, then you would have to write your own decorator.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The reason I've not accepted this as answer is because I've not tried it out yet. I am in middle of implementing something new. Once i am done with it I'll come back to this and give it a try.

Comment: Waiting for you to try it out then.